# The use of the definite article with the noun "now"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I found it in [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/s_iwrt7D5OA). It is at around 1minute and 44 second. Here is the context:

> Another change in psychology: many historians of **the** now note that globalization has also led to a celebration of individualism.

I have checked a few dictionaries, and I could not find any example where the noun *now* was used with the definite article. Could you pleasd tell me why the host used it. Does *the* bear any additional meaning in the sentence?

Comment: Note that, logically, it's nonsensical to study the present from a historical perspective . . .

Comment: Maybe the narrator thought that this cute phrasing would avoid a misunderstanding, that "many historians of the present" means "many currently working historians."

Answer (score 1):

One day I'll have to watch this 'crash course' & how he seems to torture the language ... but not today -

"of the now" is an idiom simply meaning "now" or "at present", "currently", "in this day & age", colloquially "these days".

Comment: See also 'the here and now' meaning 'the present time': [the here and now (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/here-and-now)

Comment: I have certainly heard of "the here and now", but never of "the now."